# Sort by two values prioritizing on one of them

Tags: javascript, sorting

How would I sort this data by `count` and `year` values in ascending order prioritizing on the `count` value?

```
//sort this
var data = [
    { count: '12', year: '1956' },
    { count: '1', year: '1971' },
    { count: '33', year: '1989' },
    { count: '33', year: '1988' }
];
//to get this
var data = [
    { count: '1', year: '1971' },
    { count: '12', year: '1956' },
    { count: '33', year: '1988' },
    { count: '33', year: '1989' },
];
```

Answer (score 110):

A simple solution is:

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.count - b.count || a.year - b.year;
});
```

This works because if *count* is different, then the sort is based on that. If *count* is the same, the first expression returns 0 which converts to *false* and the result of the second expression is used (i.e. the sort is based on *year*).

Comment: Nice usage of 0 as falsey!

Comment: ES version:  data.sort((a,b)=>(a.count - b.count || a.year - b.year));

Answer (score 102):

([See the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnW3r/))

```js
var data = [
    { count: '12', year: '1956' },
    { count: '1', year: '1971' },
    { count: '33', year: '1989' },
    { count: '33', year: '1988' }
];

console.log(data.sort(function (x, y) {
    var n = x.count - y.count;
    if (n !== 0) {
        return n;
    }

    return x.year - y.year;
}));
```

Comment: one-liner `data.sort(function (x, y) { return x.count - y.count || x.year - y.year; });`

Answer (score 16):

You can use JavaScript's [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) array method ([**try it out**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcWgf/)):

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    // Sort by count
    var dCount = a.count - b.count;
    if(dCount) return dCount;

    // If there is a tie, sort by year
    var dYear = a.year - b.year;
    return dYear;
});
```

Note: This changes the original array. If you need to make a copy first, you can do so:

```
var dataCopy = data.slice(0);
```

Comment: check my one-liner on the question above

Answer (score 12):

Based on great @RobG [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27993435/79191), this is a generic function to sort by multiple different properties, using a JS2015 tricky on `map + find`:

```
let sortBy = (p, a) => a.sort((i, j) => p.map(v => i[v] - j[v]).find(r => r))

sortBy(['count', 'year'], data)
```

Also, if you prefer, a traditional JS version (use with caution due to [find compatibility](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Array.prototype_methods_Array.prototype.find) in old browsers):

```
var sortBy = function (properties, targetArray) {
  targetArray.sort(function (i, j) {
    return properties.map(function (prop) {
      return i[prop] - j[prop];
    }).find(function (result) {
      return result;
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 6):

you have to work out this problem like this way

```
var customSort = function(name, type){
     return function(o, p){
         var a, b;
         if(o && p && typeof o === 'object' && typeof p === 'object'){
            a = o[name];
            b = p[name];
           if(a === b){
              return typeof type === 'function' ? type(o, p) : o;
           }

           if(typeof a=== typeof b){
              return a < b ? -1 : 1;
            }
          return typeof a < typeof b ? -1 : 1;
        }
     };
```

};

e.g :
 data.sort(customSort('year', customSort('count')));

Comment: an optional reverse would be awesome to have in here.

Answer (score 4):

user this where 'count'-> first priority and 'year'-> second priority

```
data.sort(function(a,b){
  return a['count']<b['count']?-1:(a['count']>b['count']?1:(a['year']<b['year']?-1:1));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to sort **strings** in alphabetical order rather than numbers, here's a sample problem and its solution.

**Example Problem:** Array of arrays (*finalArray*) with first entry a folder path and second entry the file name; sort so that array is arranged by folder first, and within identical folders, by file name.

E.g. after sorting you expect:

```
[['folder1', 'abc.jpg'], 
 ['folder1', 'xyz.jpg'],
 ['folder2', 'def.jpg'],
 ['folder2', 'pqr.jpg']]
```

Refer to [Array.prototype.sort() - compareFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
finalArray.sort((x: any, y: any): number => {
  const folder1: string = x[0].toLowerCase();
  const folder2: string = y[0].toLowerCase();
  const file1: string = x[1].toLowerCase();
  const file2: string = y[1].toLowerCase();

  if (folder1 > folder2) {
    return 1;
  } else if (folder1 === folder2 && file1 > file2) {
    return 1;
  } else if (folder1 === folder2 && file1 === file2) {
    return 0;
  } else if (folder1 === folder2 && file1 < file2) {
    return -1;
  } else if (folder1 < folder2) {
    return -1;
  }
});
```

Keep in mind, "Z" comes before "a" (capitals first according to *Unicode code point*) which is why I have *toLowerCase()*. The problem the above implementation does not solve is that "10abc" will come before "9abc".

Answer (score -4):

Simply do:

```
array.sort((a,b)=>a[1]-b[1])
```

Replace 1 inside the brackets depending on the index based on which you need sorting.

To generalize, let me add the snippet below:

```
array.sort((a,b)=>a[i]-b[i])
```

I've seen many do this using a full function, which isn't necessary when a simple arrow function can do the job.

Keep it simple!

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is answering a different question. This answer is if a person wants to dynamically sort based on a property, in this case: "i". The OP wants to sort 2 distinct columns, on after the other, in a single sort call.