# JavaScript sort array by multiple (number) fields

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

How can I implement a

```
 ORDER BY sort1 DESC, sort2 DESC
```

logic in an JSON array like such:

```
    var items = '[
          {
            "sort1": 1,
            "sort2": 3,
            "name" : "a",
          },
          {
            "sort1": 1,
            "sort2": 2,
            "name" : "b",
          },
          {
            "sort1": 2,
            "sort2": 1,
            "name" : "c",
          }
    ]';
```

resulting in the new order :

```
b,a,c
```

Comment: Why are you putting your Array syntax inside (broken) string literal syntax?

Comment: I'm using JSON like this, is there a better way?

Comment: Since you're assigning the Array to the `items` variable, you're already in a JavaScript environment, so it doesn't make too much sense to first represent it as JSON markup, then parse it. If that was meant to represent JSON markup being sent from the server, then a better representation is to get rid of the extra `var items = ...;` syntax, and just show it as markup with a note explaining that it's your server side markup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort by two values prioritizing on one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576714/sort-by-two-values-prioritizing-on-one-of-them)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You should design your sorting function accordingly:

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.sort1 - b.sort1  ||  a.sort2 - b.sort2;
});
```

(because `||` operator has lower precedence than `-` one, it's not necessary to use parenthesis here).

The logic is simple: if `a.sort1 - b.sort1` expression evaluates to 0 (so these properties are equal), it will proceed with evaluating `||` expression - and return the result of `a.sort2 - b.sort2`.

As a sidenote, your `items` is actually a string literal, you have to `JSON.parse` to get an array:

```js
const itemsStr = `[{
    "sort1": 1,
    "sort2": 3,
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "sort1": 1,
    "sort2": 2,
    "name": "b"
  },
  {
    "sort1": 2,
    "sort2": 1,
    "name": "c"
  }
]`;
const items = JSON.parse(itemsStr);
items.sort((a, b) => a.sort1 - b.sort1 || a.sort2 - b.sort2);
console.log(items);
```

Comment: using operator `-` might cause problem since the value might be strings.

Comment: I'm afraid you miss the point here, both in your comment and in your answer. Using `-` instead of `<` is the way to enforce comparing the operands as numbers, not as strings. Remember, `'12' < '3'` evaluates to `true` in JavaScript.

Comment: That’s exactly what I am saying. - only applies to numbers. I am not saying you are wrong. I am providing a general solution as I said in my answer.

Comment: `- only applies to numbers` - no, it's not. '12' - '3' evaluates to 9 (> 0), placing the former operand higher. '12' < '3' evaluates to `true`, reversing the order.

Comment: ‘12’ should be less than ‘3’.

Comment: Remember, explicit is better than implicit. If you want values to be compared as strings in _any case_, use [String.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) instead. `<` is ambiguous; its result depends on operands types - and type juggling, if those are different.

Comment: This discussion is meaningless. The title said it is `number`, then it should be number. If it is string probably you need to take care of 'abc' which `-` won't work. localeCompare() is handy BTW.

Comment: The `<` would still be the wrong operation to use, as you only want to run the second comparison for numbers that are equal in the first comparison. The `-` operand can capture all 3 cases of a comparison (>0, 0, <0)

Answer (score 9):

You can avoid hardcoding by create a general function

```
function sortByMultipleKey(keys) {
    return function(a, b) {
        if (keys.length == 0) return 0; // force to equal if keys run out
        key = keys[0]; // take out the first key
        if (a[key] < b[key]) return -1; // will be 1 if DESC
        else if (a[key] > b[key]) return 1; // will be -1 if DESC
        else return sortByMultipleKey(keys.slice(1))(a, b);
    }
}
```

Running

```
items.sort(sortByMultipleKey(['sort1', 'sort2']));
```

will have you

```
[ { sort1: 1, sort2: 2, name: 'b' },
  { sort1: 1, sort2: 3, name: 'a' },
  { sort1: 2, sort2: 1, name: 'c' } ]
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but this implementation of generic function is way too inefficient. Not only using recursion here is dubious (you can just iterate over list of keys until comparison results in non-zero), for each 'comparison miss' there's a new instance of comparison function generated. Compare your code to [lodash implementation](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.6.0-npm-packages/lodash.orderby/index.js#L1327), for example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const itemsStr = `[{
    "sort1": 1,
    "sort2": 3,
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "sort1": 1,
    "sort2": 2,
    "name": "b"
  },
  {
    "sort1": 2,
    "sort2": 1,
    "name": "c"
  }
]`;
const items = JSON.parse(itemsStr);
items.sort((a, b) => a.sort1 - b.sort1 || a.sort2 - b.sort2);
console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.sort1 !== b.sort1) {
        return a.sort1 - b.sort1; // Sort by sort1 field
    } else {
        return a.sort2 - b.sort2; // If sort1 fields are equal, sort by sort2 field
    }
});

var result = items.map(function(item) {
    return item.name;
}).join(',');

console.log(result); // Output: b,a,c
```