# javascript sort array by multiple (mixed number and string) fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

This question is different than ones pointed to because I want to sort by a string and THEN a number and a string, etc.

I have been going off of

[javascript sort array by multiple (number) fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211709/javascript-sort-array-by-multiple-number-fields)

I have the following for my data:

```
function GetStudentList(){
    var sl = [
    {
          "ClassOrder": 1,
          "LastName": "Blow",
          "FirstName": "Joe",
          "Class": "170-2"
    },
    {
          "ClassOrder": 2,
          "LastName": "Jane",
          "FirstName": "Sally",
          "Class": "170-1"
    },
    {
          "ClassOrder": 1,
          "LastName": "Belmont",
          "FirstName": "John",
          "Class": "170-1"
    }
]
return(sl);
}
```

Then I call the code:

```
var selectedStudents = GetStudentList();
selectedStudents.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.LastName - b,LastName;
};
```

It seems to work when I trace it in browser, but as soon as I leave the sort function, the selectedStudents array reverts back. It does appear to work, but only with the ClassOrder data. Then also, IF I try to sort by the ClassOrder and THEN the LastName, nothing works again.

```
return a.ClassOrder - b.ClassOrder || a.LastName - b.LastName
```

Comment: You cannot compare strings by `-`, that only works on numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't compare strings with `-`. Instead, use `<` or `>` for sorting descending or ascending respectively.

```js
let sl = [
  {
    "ClassOrder": 1,
    "LastName": "Blow",
    "FirstName": "Joe",
    "Class": "170-2"
  },
  {
    "ClassOrder": 2,
    "LastName": "Jane",
    "FirstName": "Sally",
    "Class": "170-1"
  },
  {
    "ClassOrder": 1,
    "LastName": "Belmont",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "Class": "170-1"
  }
];

sl.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.LastName > b.LastName) return 1;
  else if (a.LastName < b.LastName) return -1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(sl);
```

Comment: [NO!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)

Comment: This works SO Awesome, but why do my editors (i.e. Dreamweaver and Visual Studio highlight "=>" and say it is a syntax error?

Comment: @Bergi You are right; my apologies.

Comment: @Keltanis Most likely because '=>' is ECMAScript 6 syntax. `( ) => { }` translates to `function() { }`

Comment: Why two comparisons, and not just `a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName)`, I wonder?