# Sort array for two properties Vuejs

Tags: sorting, vue.js

How Can I sort Array object for two properties like "surname" - "name"?

I tried with concatenation but It doesn't works, because it sort only for second sorting:

```
computed:{
   sortedArray: function() {
      function name(a, b) {
         if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
         if (a.name > b.name) return 1;

         return 0;
      }
      function surname(a, b) {
         if (a.surname < b.surname) return -1;
         if (a.surname > b.surname) return 1;
         return 0;
      }

      return this.users.sort(surname).sort(name);
   }
}
```

I 'have tried also with:

```
function surname(a, b) {
   return a.surname < b.surname || a.name < b.name
}
```

But it return an array not sorted by surname / name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript sort array by multiple (number) fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211709/javascript-sort-array-by-multiple-number-fields)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you sort an array on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230/how-do-you-sort-an-array-on-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually pretty close.

The problem is when you do:

```
return this.users.sort(surname).sort(name);
```

You first sort by `surname` and **then** by `name` **ignoring** `surname`.

The solution is to use a function that handles both properties **at the same time**. So join those sort functions into one.

Another thing, your computed is sorting **in-place**. You probably want to clone the array and **return a sorted copy in the computed property instead**.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [
      {name: "John", surname: "Nash"},
      {name: "Paul", surname: "Pringles"},
      {name: "Bob", surname: "Pringles"},
      {name: "Bob", surname: "Abbey"},
      {name: "Alice", surname: "Abbey"},
    ]
  },
  computed:{
     sortedArray: function() {
        function surnameName(a, b) {
           if (a.surname < b.surname) return -1;
           if (a.surname > b.surname) return 1;
           if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
           if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
           return 0;
        }
        // return this.users.sort(surnameName); // sorts in-place
        return [...this.users].sort(surnameName); // shallow clone + sort
     }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>unsorted:<br>{{ users }}</p>
  <p>sorted:<br>{{ sortedArray }}</p>
</div>
```