# How to sort multiple objects with watched value? vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch

I created a `select` element in `HTML` and want to create an option for a user to sort a table by select element option `values`.

The `data` I want to sort (there will be many objects):

[image]

I am watching a select element which has a v-model value of sort:

```
  watch: {
  search: function (val) {
    if (val.length === 0) return this.filtered = this.affiliates;

    this.filtered = this.affiliates.filter(function (cont) {
      return cont.shop_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) >= 0 || cont.app_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
    });
  },
  sort: function (val) {
    console.log(this.filtered);
  },
```

How could I sort `objects` by watched value?

Data is stored in `this.filtered`

I want to sort by these values:

```
 <select v-model="sort">
          <option value="date_installed">Latest</option>
          <option value="status">Status</option>
          <option value="share">Share</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13211709/javascript-sort-array-by-multiple-number-fields) link will help you, possible duplicate of that answer

Answer (score 0):

While you **can** make it work with a `watch`, this seems like a better fit for `computed`

The sort function takes a compare function as an argument, you can dynamically compare the objects based on sort preference by passing it as a key using bracket notation for accessor.

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <select v-model="sortBy">
            <option value="date_installed">Latest</option>
            <option value="status">Status</option>
            <option value="share">Share</option>
        </select>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in filtered" :key="item.id">{{ item.app_name}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            sortBy: [],
            affiliates: [
                //...
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        filtered() {
            if (val.length === 0) return this.affiliates;
            return this.affiliates.sort( (a,b) => {
                return a[this.sortBy] - b[this.sortBy]
            });
        }
    },
}
</script>
```