# Why is an empty string in JavaScript equals to zero?

Tags: javascript, casting, type-conversion, type-coercion

I understand the concepts of type coercion and type conversion, but they don't clarify ***why*** an empty string is zero. Not NaN, but zero.

```js
console.log(Number('')) // 0
```

The only explanation I was able to found is that an empty string is a part of [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values, but it covers only a boolean context.

This [MDN docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#:%7E:text=Empty%20or%20whitespace%2Donly%20strings%20are%20converted%20to%200.) states "an empty string is zero" as a fact, as well as [Language Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-number-constructor-number-value) (if I get it right).

Is there a rationale or deeper meaning for such behavior?

Comment: I suspect because `Number()` returns `0`.

Comment: If you want NaN use parseFloat.

Answer (score 2):

JS is a very loose typed language, so when when 2 different types meet in a math expression JS tries very hard to coerce them into numbers even it could look weird.

An example when we can use `-` operator to use string and boolean types directly as numbers: [I want to sort an array with multiple criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78207998/i-want-to-sort-an-array-with-multiple-criteria/78208441#78208441)

My guess since `''` is falsy, it's convertible to `false` which is easily expressed as `0`. I guess `Number(' ')` looks more weird btw but that's what we have in the language's specification ‍♂️:

```js
console.log(Number(' '))
```

I guess it's here: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-runtime-semantics-stringnumericvalue.

Languages like JS and PHP initially were for just adding a bit of interactivity and conditional rendering to web pages, so preserved some quirks historically for backward compatibility (you cannot change a spec and ruin WWW) like `NaN == NaN`:

```js
console.log(NaN == NaN);
```

At least all those quirks are well known and documented.

Comment: Why multiple whitespaces looks more weird though? It's just stripped the same way as `Number('   5   ')`, so it's still `Number('')`

Comment: @Azenon it's not falsy

Comment: Yeah, but the value itself is stripped to the empty string, which is falsy