# Sort an array of objects by multiple properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var a = [
    { id: 1, score: 1, isCut: false, dnf: false },
    { id: 2, score: 2, isCut: false, dnf: false },
    { id: 3, score: 3, isCut: false, dnf: false },
    { id: 4, score: 4, isCut: false, dnf: false },
    { id: 5, score: 5, isCut: true, dnf: true },
    { id: 6, score: 6, isCut: true, dnf: false },
    { id: 7, score: 7, isCut: true, dnf: false },
    { id: 8, score: 8, isCut: true, dnf: false },
    { id: 9, score: 9, isCut: true, dnf: false },
    { id: 10, score: 0, isCut: false, dnf: false },
    { id: 11, score: -1, isCut: false, dnf: false },
    { id: 12, score: -2, isCut: false, dnf: true },
    { id: 13, score: -3, isCut: false, dnf: false },
    { id: 14, score: -4, isCut: false, dnf: false },
    { id: 15, score: -5, isCut: false, dnf: false },
    { id: 16, score: 10, isCut: true, dnf: false }
];
```

I need to group and sort the array by the following criteria:

1. if `dnf` is true, object goes to bottom; all `dnf`-objects should be sorted by score
2. if `isCut` is true, object goes to bottom, but above `dnf`s; all `isCut`-objects should be sorted by score
3. rest should be sorted by `score`, and if the scores are equal, by `id`

Comment: Array.sort accepts a comparator function.

Comment: Yes, but how to implement it, that is the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576714/sort-by-two-values-prioritizing-on-one-of-them     look at this, I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Updated) Here's the answer of question you mentioned in comment.

```
a.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.dnf != b.dnf) {
    return a.dnf ? 1 : -1;
  }
  if (!(a.dnf && b.dnf) && a.isCut != b.isCut) {
    return a.isCut ? 1 : -1;
  }
  if (a.score != b.score) {
    return b.score - a.score; // descending
  }
  return b.id - a.id; // descending
});
```

Result:

```
[
  {"id":4,"score":4,"isCut":false,"dnf":false},   // the rest: order by score, id
  {"id":3,"score":3,"isCut":false,"dnf":false},   //
  {"id":2,"score":2,"isCut":false,"dnf":false},   //
  {"id":1,"score":1,"isCut":false,"dnf":false},   //
  {"id":10,"score":0,"isCut":false,"dnf":false},  //
  {"id":11,"score":-1,"isCut":false,"dnf":false}, //
  {"id":13,"score":-3,"isCut":false,"dnf":false}, //
  {"id":14,"score":-4,"isCut":false,"dnf":false}, //
  {"id":15,"score":-5,"isCut":false,"dnf":false}, //
  {"id":16,"score":10,"isCut":true,"dnf":false}, // isCut: order by score, id
  {"id":9,"score":9,"isCut":true,"dnf":false},   //
  {"id":8,"score":8,"isCut":true,"dnf":false},   //
  {"id":7,"score":7,"isCut":true,"dnf":false},   //
  {"id":6,"score":6,"isCut":true,"dnf":false},   //
  {"id":5,"score":5,"isCut":true,"dnf":true},   // dnf: order by score, id
  {"id":12,"score":-2,"isCut":false,"dnf":true} //
]
```

Comment: This is ordering by `dnf` first. `isCut` will not be ordered accurately. You first want all items where `isCut` is true followed by items where `isCut` is false.

Comment: @amberlamps I can't understand. Dosen't OP want to let `dnf` objects to bottom? Then we should order by `dnf` first.

Comment: You understood correctly, but he wants `isCut` above that if it is `true`. So it can look like `true/true`, `true/false`, `false/true` in that order.

Comment: You have to test it with lots of different data to be really sure, but I looks really fine so far. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, which uses an array for the sort order, which is irregular, if using `dnf` and `isCut` property without looking at both. If we take a both values to a truth table, then the sort order does not reflect the wanted order.

> ```
>                    2*dnf+isCut
>     dnf     isCut     value     order
> --------  --------  --------  --------
>      0         0         0         0
>      0         1         1         1
>      1         1         3         2
>      1         0         2         3
> ```

To correct the sort order, I suggest to use an array for getting the right order.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, score: 1, isCut: false, dnf: false }, { id: 2, score: 2, isCut: false, dnf: false }, { id: 3, score: 3, isCut: false, dnf: false }, { id: 4, score: 4, isCut: false, dnf: false }, { id: 5, score: 5, isCut: true, dnf: true }, { id: 6, score: 6, isCut: true, dnf: false }, { id: 7, score: 7, isCut: true, dnf: false }, { id: 8, score: 8, isCut: true, dnf: false }, { id: 9, score: 9, isCut: true, dnf: false }, { id: 10, score: 0, isCut: false, dnf: false }, { id: 11, score: -1, isCut: false, dnf: false }, { id: 12, score: -2, isCut: false, dnf: true }, { id: 13, score: -3, isCut: false, dnf: false }, { id: 14, score: -4, isCut: false, dnf: false }, { id: 15, score: -5, isCut: false, dnf: false }, { id: 16, score: 10, isCut: true, dnf: false }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    function order(dnf, isCut) { return [0, 1, 3, 2][dnf * 2 + isCut]; }

    return order(a.dnf, a.isCut) - order(b.dnf, b.isCut) || b.score - a.score;
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **comparator** function from Array

you can check answers here : [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript)

Comment: This only works for strings. Author has multiple types to deal with.