# Sorting an array of object by value in a specific order based on another object for D3 Visualization

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have an array of object containing colors. I need to sort the array by the color in a specific order.

I used the [answer from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39506725/javascript-sort-array-of-objects-by-a-property-based-on-a-special-order/39506825) to sort the array in a specific order and it has mostly worked. The issue that I face right now is that when I visualise it using D3Js, instead of clubbing all the objects with matching colors together there is repetition of the colors in specified order. Why is this happening and how can I get the correct sorting.

```
    var sortOrder = {"#F39849": 0, "#E94927": 1, "#538296": 2, "#CCCCCC": 3};

    var sortedData = data.sort(function (p1, p2) {
      return sortOrder[p1.colors] - sortOrder[p2.colors];
    });
```

full code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/diviseed/r98eawzL/32/)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that this has to do with the values in your data that are don't have `colors` attributes.  There are at least a few of them I see.

If you had some handling for unknown values, say

```js
    var sortOrder = {"#F39849": 0, "#E94927": 1, "#538296": 2, "#CCCCCC": 3, "unknown" : 100};
```

and

```js
    return sortOrder[p1.colors || 'unknown'] - sortOrder[p2.colors || 'unknown'];
```

It will likely work.

You might also want to handle the case where `colors` is found, but is not in your list, which probably can be handled with

```js
return ((sortOrder[p1.colors || 'unknown'] + 1) || Infinity) - 
       ((sortOrder[p2.colors || 'unknown'] + 1) || Infinity);
```

The `Infinity`s are to move any not found to the end of the list, and we need to `+1`s to avoid doing `0 || Infinity`.