# How to sort an array based on a boolean prop and a name prop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that look like this:

```
[
  {
    name: s1,
    isDefault: false
  },
  {
    name: s2,
    isDefault: true
  },
  {
    name: s3,
    isDefault: false
  }
]
```

I want to sort this array so that the element with `isDefault: true` is placed first, and have the rest follow this object in alphabetical order.

In other words:

```
[
  {
    name: s2,
    isDefault: true
  },
  {
    name: s1,
    isDefault: false
  },
  {
    name: s3,
    isDefault: false
  }
]
```

I know how to accomplish the first condition:

```
objPanoramas.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.isDefault < b.isDefault
})
```

How can I integrate the second condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```js
objPanoramas = [{
  name: "s1",
  isDefault: false
},{
  name: "s1",
  isDefault: true
}, {
  name: "s2",
  isDefault: true
}, {
  name: "s3",
  isDefault: false
}]


objPanoramas.sort((a, b) => {
  if ((a.isDefault && b.isDefault) || (!a.isDefault && !b.isDefault)) {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
  }else{
    return !a.isDefault
  }
})

console.log(objPanoramas);
```

Comment: You should return [positive, zero or negative value from callback](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp). Your solution would work because of automatic type conversion, but it's not the best practice.

Comment: I'll edit my answer based on your suggestion... thanks

Comment: I came out with this: `objPanoramas.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.isDefault !== b.isDefault) {
      return a.isDefault < b.isDefault
    }
    return a.name > b.name
  })` Does it do the same as your code?

Comment: basically yes, but as suggested by @yariash compare the strings using the proper comparison function

Answer (score 2):

```
objPanoramas.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.isDefault == b.isDefault) {
    name1 = a.name;
    name2 = b.name;
    return name1<name2?-1:(name1>name2?1:0)
  }
  return a.isDefault < b.isDefault
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return positive  value, zero or negative from [callback of sort](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp):

```
objPanoramas.sort((a, b) => {
     if(a.isDefault == b.isDefault) {
         return a.name.localeCompare(b.name); //in case both values are equal do alphabetical sort
     } else if(a.isDefault) {
          return 1; //else if a.isDefault is true return positive value.
     }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactely what you need:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4576720/6482090

As you can see into this post the solution is to check both value inside your sort().

Look at the example on that post!