# Natural sort in multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a solution to get multidimensional arrays naturally sorted with JavaScript. I found some solutions sorting multidimensional arrays or sorting naturally, but I found no solution for both requirements.

I also cannot combine the solutions. 
here is what the array looks like:

```
var content = [
{0: 'somename', 1: '10.1.1.100', 2: 'aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff'},
{0: 'someothername', 1: '10.1.1.12', 2: '11-22-33-44-55-66'}
];
```

As you can see the array contains servernames, IP addresses and MAC addresses. It is some table content written in this array. 
To sort the table I want to sort this array.

Do you have any clever idea how to handle this?

Thank you for your help.

edit: OK maybe, I have to be more specific: 
There is no problem to sort a multidimensional array. I am able to sort this array for MAC, IP or name. It is a simple one line code. 
The problem is to sort them naturally. Whene you have alphanumerical strings like server name or IP you want to sort the example list:

```
{a3, a12, a100, a1}
```

like this:

```
{a1, a3, a12, a100}
```

This is called natural sorting. 
The "normal" sorting instead looks like this:

```
{a1, a100, a12, a3}
```

I found several algos for sorting naturally but I was not able to prepare them to sort a multidimenional array.

Comment: If you provide an example case I am pretty sure within minutes you will either get a duplicate response or many answers.

Comment: Would be good to give an example of your array :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort 2 dimensional array by column value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096872/how-to-sort-2-dimensional-array-by-column-value)

Comment: Dont think its a duplicate, cause I need a natural sort. Your example is a normal sort.

Comment: First, how is that a multi-dimensional array? It's an array of objects?

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: How do you want to sort it? According to the servername, the IP, or the MAC?

Comment: I want to choose if it gets sorted by mac, ip or name. The wanted result should be a natural sort - 100 is bigger than 12. When the sort goes for IP, sort should look like this: {0: 'someothername', 1: '10.1.1.12', 2: '11-22-33-44-55-66'}, {0: 'somename', 1: '10.1.1.100', 2: 'aa-bb-cc-dd-ee-ff'}
Thank you for all your comments and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems trivial to sort according to the properties other than the IP address. If you would like to sort according to the IP addresses you may do as follows;

```js
var ipads = ["192.168.1.1", "192.168.0.1", "10.10.1.1", "178.16.62.42", "42.14.1.1", "42.15.1.1", "178.16.61.42", "192.168.1.2", "0.255.255.255","9.255.255.255","10.0.0.1"],
   result = ipads.map(a => a.split("."))
                 .sort((a,b) => (a[0]-b[0])*16777216 + (a[1]-b[1])*65536 + (a[2]-b[2])*256 + a[3]-b[3])
                 .map(e => e.join("."));
console.log(result);
```

If you would like to sort with priority of the properties then there are [many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576714/4543207) in SO that you can apply this.

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't help. I specified my request a little more in the original post.