# Sort array first by string and then by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Well, I have an array objects with random values,
Ex.

```
var value = [
    {"date":"06/11/2017","status":"B"},
    {"date":"06/11/2017","status":"B"},
    {"date":"15/05/2017","status":"R"},
    {"date":"15/05/2017","status":"R"},
    {"date":"14/05/2018","status":"R"},
    {"date":"05/05/2017","status":"R"},
    {"date":null,"status":"W"},
    {"date":null,"status":"W"},
    {"date":null,"status":"W"},
    {"date":"05/11/2017","status":"B"},
    {"date":"27/07/2017","status":"R"},
    {"date":"14/05/2018","status":"R"},
    {"date":"27/07/201","status":"R"},
    {"date":"14/05/2018","status":"R"},
    {"date":"26/02/2018","status":"R"},
    {"date":null,"status":"W"}
];
```

I wanted to sort this array firstly by key `status` & then by key `date` as,

**Output:**

```
var result =  [
    {"date":"05/11/2017","status":"B"}, 
    {"date":"06/11/2017","status":"B"},
    {"date":"06/11/2017","status":"B"},
    {"date":"05/05/2017","status":"R"},
    {"date":"15/05/2017","status":"R"},
    {"date":"15/05/2017","status":"R"},
    {"date":"27/07/2017","status":"R"},
    {"date":"14/05/2018","status":"R"},
    {"date":"14/05/2018","status":"R"},
    {"date":"14/05/2018","status":"R"},
    {"date":"26/02/2018","status":"R"},
    {"date":"27/07/2018","status":"R"},     
    {"date":null,"status":"W"},
    {"date":null,"status":"W"},
    {"date":null,"status":"W"},
    {"date":null,"status":"W"}
];

/*I tried few generic code to sort, */   
var result = value.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aValue = (a.date) ?  a.date: 0;
    var bValue = (b.date) ?  b.date: 0;
    return a.status - b.status ||  aValue - bValue;
});
```

I referred few examples [SO Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-javascript-objects/979325#979325) but not getting expected output. Please suggest me best way to get this.

Comment: There isn't a key called `name` in your example?

Comment: @user184994. Please check it once I have made modification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort by two values prioritizing on one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576714/sort-by-two-values-prioritizing-on-one-of-them)

Comment: is the status more relevant than the given date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work?

```
value = value.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a === b || (a.status === b.status && a.date === b.date)) return 0;

  if (a.status > b.status) return 1;
  if (a.status < b.status) return -1;

  if (a.date > b.date) return 1;
  if (a.date < b.date) return -1;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> return a.status - b.status ||  aValue - bValue;
> ```

The values you are dealing with are not numbers! You can't subtract one from the other.

Also: Don't use nested ternary operators. It makes it very hard to understand the code.

Use `if` statements. They are much more readable.

I *think* this is what you are looking for, but your description of the problem isn't clear. This should, however, show you the principles so you can tweak it as you want.

```
const a_is_first = -1;
const b_is_first = 1;

function compare(a, b) {
    // Sort and group by status first. Sort by date within the statuses.
    if (a.status < b.status) {
         return a_is_first;
    } else if (a.status > b.status) {
         return b_is_first;
    } else { // They are the same
         var a__date = convert_to_a_date_object(a.date);
         var b__date = convert_to_a_date_object(b.date);
         if (a__date < b__date) {
             return a_is_first;
         } else if (a__date > b__date) {
             return b_is_first;
         } else {
             return 0;
         }
    }
}

value.sort(compare);
```

The implementation of `convert_to_a_date_object` is left as an exercise for the reader. Remember it has to handle `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this helps

```
value.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.status.toUpperCase(),
    nameB = b.status.toUpperCase();
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your date is under format "dd/mm/yyyy". You can use `Date.parse("11/05/2017")` (with format "mm/dd/yyyy", see [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for more formats) to return the number of milliseconds and compare. For the `status`, you can use `status.charCodeAt(0)` to get ASCII value and compare.
Assuming that you have a good date format, here is the solution:

```
value.sort(function(a, b) {
  var diff = Date.parse(a.date) - Date.parse(b.date);
  if (diff === 0) {
    return a.status.charCodeAt(0) - b.status.charCodeAt(0);
  } 
  return diff;
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could take `status` for sorting and if equal take a date string in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation for sorting. ISO 6801 allowes to use a sorting by string without taking a date object.

```js
var array = [{ date: "06/11/2017", status: "B" }, { date: "06/11/2017", status: "B" }, { date: "15/05/2017", status: "R" }, { date: "15/05/2017", status: "R" }, { date: "14/05/2018", status: "R" }, { date: "05/05/2017", status: "R" }, { date: null, status: "W" }, { date: null, status: "W" }, { date: null, status: "W" }, { date: "05/11/2017", status: "B" }, { date: "27/07/2017", status: "R" }, { date: "14/05/2018", status: "R" }, { date: "27/07/2017", status: "R" }, { date: "14/05/2018", status: "R" }, { date: "26/02/2018", status: "R" }, { date: null, status: "W" }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getDate(d) {
        return d ? d.replace(/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/, '$3-$2-$1') : '';
    }

    return a.status.localeCompare(b.status) || getDate(a.date).localeCompare(getDate(b.date));
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```