# Having certain behavior occur within the ranges between array values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of values, specifically pixel offsets of a certain type of element.

Let's say they are in an array `arrScroll[]` with values `[5, 10, 15, 50, 100, 250]`.

If my window scrolls past 5 pixels but not past 10 pixels, I get the index 0. If my window scrolls past 15 pixels but not past 50 pixels, I get the index 2. If it scrolls back below 10 pixels but not below 5, I get the index 0 again.

What I'm trying to do is find a graceful way (instead of a ton of conditionals for each possible range, as the number of ranges can change) to always get the lower of the two indexes of the scroll range that I am in, except at the range 0 to `arrScroll[0]`, in which case I pass a different value than the index.

Another example: if I am in the range of `arrScroll[3]` and `arrScroll[4]` then I will obtain the index 3. Only once I pass the position of the higher index number do I get its index.

**This has nothing to do with sorting as the values are already sorted from smallest to greatest. On a scroll event listener, I simply want to obtain the index of the lower of the two values comprising the index.**

What would be the best way to organize this so that it can function for an array of arbitrary length?

**More complete example:**

I have the colors red, blue, and green. I have an array with values `[100, 200, 300]`. When my window scrolls past 100 pixels but not past 200 pixels, I will have something like `$(element).css('background-color', colorArr[index])` where the color in `colorArr[]` at index 0 is red.

Then if the window scrolls past 200, but not past 300, I run the same code snippet, but the index is now 1 and the color is blue.

If I scroll back below 200 pixels but not below 100 pixels, the index is once again 0 and the color passed is red.

This is trivial to create with if statements if the length of the array is known, but I don't know how to do it for an array of arbitrary length.

Comment: Are you wanting the lower of the indexes, or the lower of the values at that index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort by two values prioritizing on one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576714/sort-by-two-values-prioritizing-on-one-of-them)

Comment: @Taplar Shouldn't matter, so long as I have the lower index I can pull the value from the array.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards This isn't related to sorting as the values are already sorted.

Comment: This makes literally no sense as the array is already sorted, the smaller index always wins.

Comment: @rottenoats This shouldn't have anything to do with sorting in the first place. On a scroll event listener, I am trying to have different behavior occur as the page scrolls in different pixel ranges. Such ranges are contained in the mentioned array.

Comment: I know this has nothing to do with sorting, however you mention that the array is already sorted, so what's the problem? You have two indexes 3 and 4 and you want the lowest value of the two... it'll be the lower index all the time since it's already sorted.

Comment: @rottenoats Yes, that's the idea. But if I don't know how long the length of the array is, I can't create dozens of if statements and hope it works. I was wondering if there was a more graceful way. I've made a more complete example in the original post to showcase my exact use for this.

Comment: Akor check my answer, played around with some values and should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you're seeking to find index based on a value?

```js
let arr = [5, 10, 15, 50, 100, 250];
let colorArr = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "black"]
//fake listener
let scrollListener = (pixelScrolled) => {
   let index = (arr.findIndex((element)=>pixelScrolled<element)+arr.length)%(arr.length+1);
   $(document.body).css('background-color', colorArr[index])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="(()=>scrollListener(9))()">fake scroll toggle : 9</button>
<button onclick="(()=>scrollListener(49))()">fake scroll toggle : 49</button>
<button onclick="(()=>scrollListener(250))()">fake scroll toggle :  250</button>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd iterate on your arrScroll values starting from the begining, assuming your offsets are always sorted in a growing order and break as soon as your test position is greater than the tested index

```js
var test = function (position, offsets) {
    for (var index = 0; index < offsets.length - 1; index++) {
      if (position < offsets[index]) break;
    }
    
    return index > 0 ? index - 1 : 'something';
}

// will return index 1 cuz 4 is bw 1 and 5
console.log(test(4, [0, 1, 5, 10, 20, 42]))

// will return 3
console.log(test(12, [0, 1, 5, 10, 20, 42]))

// would return 0, but would return "something" since this is your special case
console.log(test(16, [20, 100]))
```

That way you iterate only on part of your offset arrays, exiting as soon as possible