# sort JSON array by string and number properties in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

Best way to sort results of JSON array? I need to re-order by `customer` then `invoice` keeping all customers together with ascending `invoice` values. Same as a SQL would be: `SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY customer, invoice ASC`. Here is attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/ramd6u83/

```js
var values = [];
for (var invoice in json) {
  values.push(json[invoice]);
}
var str = values.sort().join('\n');
console.log(str);

var json = [{
    "autonum": "26",
    "date": "2017-04-17",
    "customer": "jad Rasul\r\n",
    "address": "Washington, DC 20017",
    "invoice": "20170412",
    "sales": "450.00",
    "paid": "0.00",
    "owed": "450.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2017-04-17 15:35:08",
    "cust_id": "16",
    "product": "Hourly Rate",
    "description": "Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs",
    "cost": "150.00",
    "quantity": "3",
    "price": "450.00",
    "timestamp": "2017-04-17 15:35:08"
  },
  {
    "autonum": "27",
    "date": "2017-07-31",
    "customer": "jad Rasul\r\n",
    "address": "Washington, DC 20017",
    "invoice": "20170731",
    "sales": "300.00",
    "paid": "0.00",
    "owed": "300.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2017-07-31 14:19:02",
    "cust_id": "19",
    "product": "Hourly Rate",
    "description": "Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs",
    "cost": "150.00",
    "quantity": "2",
    "price": "300.00",
    "timestamp": "2017-08-01 17:19:02"
  },
  {
    "autonum": "31",
    "date": "2018-06-02",
    "customer": "jad Rasul\r\n",
    "address": "1160 Varnum Street\r\nSuite 114\r\nWashington, DC 20017\r\n\t\t\t",
    "invoice": "20180611",
    "sales": "300.00",
    "paid": "0.00",
    "owed": "300.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2018-07-02 15:13:34",
    "cust_id": "22",
    "product": "Hourly Rate",
    "description": "Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs",
    "cost": "150.00",
    "quantity": "2",
    "price": "300.00",
    "timestamp": "2018-07-02 15:13:34"
  },
  {
    "autonum": "90",
    "date": "2017-02-05",
    "customer": "jad Rasul",
    "address": "Washington, DC 20017",
    "invoice": "20170205",
    "sales": "450.00",
    "paid": "150.00",
    "owed": "300.00",
    "tax": "2.00",
    "misc": "2017-02-05 20:20:25",
    "cust_id": "1",
    "product": "Hourly Rate",
    "description": "Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs",
    "cost": "150.00",
    "quantity": "3",
    "price": "450.00",
    "timestamp": "2019-02-05 02:22:47"
  },
  {
    "autonum": "91",
    "date": "2017-02-05",
    "customer": "jad Rasul",
    "address": "Washington, DC 20017",
    "invoice": "20170205",
    "sales": "300.00",
    "paid": "50.00",
    "owed": "250.00",
    "tax": "2.00",
    "misc": "2017-02-05 20:21:18",
    "cust_id": "2",
    "product": "Hourly Rate",
    "description": "Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs",
    "cost": "150.00",
    "quantity": "2",
    "price": "300.00",
    "timestamp": "2019-02-05 02:22:47"
  },
  {
    "autonum": "43",
    "date": "2018-11-12",
    "customer": "jad Rasul",
    "address": "Washington, DC 20017\r\n\t\t\t",
    "invoice": "20181024",
    "sales": "893.00",
    "paid": "300.00",
    "owed": "593.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2018-11-12 18:32:13",
    "cust_id": "27",
    "product": "Win10-key",
    "description": "OEM Windows 10 Home, 64-Bit, 1-Pack, DVD",
    "cost": "98.99",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "98.99",
    "timestamp": "2018-11-12 18:32:13"
  },
  {
    "autonum": "89",
    "date": "2019-02-25",
    "customer": "jad Rasul",
    "address": "Washington, DC 20017\r\nSuite 114",
    "invoice": "20190225",
    "sales": "375.00",
    "paid": "0.00",
    "owed": "375.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2019-02-26 02:22:47",
    "cust_id": "56",
    "product": "Hourly Rate",
    "description": "Commercial Rate - troubleshoot and repair network after Comc",
    "cost": "150.00",
    "quantity": "3",
    "price": "375.00",
    "timestamp": "2019-02-26 02:22:47"
  },
  {
    "autonum": "33",
    "date": "2018-09-02",
    "customer": "Potomac\r\n",
    "address": "Damascus, MD 20872\t\t\t",
    "invoice": "20180902",
    "sales": "467.00",
    "paid": "0.00",
    "owed": "467.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2018-09-02 22:44:09",
    "cust_id": "23",
    "product": "Hourly Rate",
    "description": "Commercial Camera Installation / Mount / Seal",
    "cost": "150.00",
    "quantity": "2",
    "price": "300.00",
    "timestamp": "2018-09-02 22:44:09"
  },
  {
    "autonum": "30",
    "date": "2017-08-14",
    "customer": "Ann Frank\r\n",
    "address": "Ellicott City, MD 21043\r\n\r\n\t\t\t",
    "invoice": "20170814",
    "sales": "350.00",
    "paid": "0.00",
    "owed": "350.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2017-08-14 17:56:52",
    "cust_id": "21",
    "product": "Hourly Rate",
    "description": "Residential Rate: Labor/Installs: 6 Kidde i12010S 10 year sm",
    "cost": "350.00",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "350.00",
    "timestamp": "2017-08-14 17:56:52"
  },
  {
    "autonum": "21",
    "date": "2017-03-22",
    "customer": "Bikes Music\r\n",
    "address": "Mery Station",
    "invoice": "20160929",
    "sales": "2416.00",
    "paid": "1000.00",
    "owed": "1416.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2017-03-22 19:51:00",
    "cust_id": "15",
    "product": "Home Depot",
    "description": "Home Depot Supplies for Shelf/mounts/braces/paint.",
    "cost": "128.50",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "128.50",
    "timestamp": "2017-03-22 19:51:00"
  },
  {
    "autonum": "83",
    "date": "2019-02-07",
    "customer": "Bikes Music",
    "address": "Mery Station",
    "invoice": "20190207",
    "sales": "95.00",
    "paid": "0.00",
    "owed": "95.00",
    "tax": "0.00",
    "misc": "2019-02-15 20:57:54",
    "cust_id": "50",
    "product": "Hourly Rate",
    "description": "Residential Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs",
    "cost": "95.00",
    "quantity": "1",
    "price": "95.00",
    "timestamp": "2019-02-15 20:57:54"
  }
];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort by two values prioritizing on one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576714/sort-by-two-values-prioritizing-on-one-of-them)

Comment: FYI it's only JSON if it is a source string (that can be be parsed). What you have is a javascript array containing javascript objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript sort array by two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129952/javascript-sort-array-by-two-fields)

Comment: I would just use lodash - `_.sortBy(values, ['customer', 'invoice'])`. You can import only the sortBy function depending on your setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort` by comparing the `customer` values first using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). If both are same, then compare the numeric values of `invoice`

```js
var json=[{"autonum":"26","date":"2017-04-17","customer":"jad Rasul\r\n","address":"Washington, DC 20017","invoice":"20170412","sales":"450.00","paid":"0.00","owed":"450.00","tax":"0.00","misc":"2017-04-17 15:35:08","cust_id":"16","product":"Hourly Rate","description":"Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs","cost":"150.00","quantity":"3","price":"450.00","timestamp":"2017-04-17 15:35:08"},{"autonum":"27","date":"2017-07-31","customer":"jad Rasul\r\n","address":"Washington, DC 20017","invoice":"20170731","sales":"300.00","paid":"0.00","owed":"300.00","tax":"0.00","misc":"2017-07-31 14:19:02","cust_id":"19","product":"Hourly Rate","description":"Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs","cost":"150.00","quantity":"2","price":"300.00","timestamp":"2017-08-01 17:19:02"},{"autonum":"31","date":"2018-06-02","customer":"jad Rasul\r\n","address":"1160 Varnum Street\r\nSuite 114\r\nWashington, DC 20017\r\n\t\t\t","invoice":"20180611","sales":"300.00","paid":"0.00","owed":"300.00","tax":"0.00","misc":"2018-07-02 15:13:34","cust_id":"22","product":"Hourly Rate","description":"Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs","cost":"150.00","quantity":"2","price":"300.00","timestamp":"2018-07-02 15:13:34"},{"autonum":"90","date":"2017-02-05","customer":"jad Rasul","address":"Washington, DC 20017","invoice":"20170205","sales":"450.00","paid":"150.00","owed":"300.00","tax":"2.00","misc":"2017-02-05 20:20:25","cust_id":"1","product":"Hourly Rate","description":"Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs","cost":"150.00","quantity":"3","price":"450.00","timestamp":"2019-02-05 02:22:47"},{"autonum":"91","date":"2017-02-05","customer":"jad Rasul","address":"Washington, DC 20017","invoice":"20170205","sales":"300.00","paid":"50.00","owed":"250.00","tax":"2.00","misc":"2017-02-05 20:21:18","cust_id":"2","product":"Hourly Rate","description":"Business Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs","cost":"150.00","quantity":"2","price":"300.00","timestamp":"2019-02-05 02:22:47"},{"autonum":"43","date":"2018-11-12","customer":"jad Rasul","address":"Washington, DC 20017\r\n\t\t\t","invoice":"20181024","sales":"893.00","paid":"300.00","owed":"593.00","tax":"0.00","misc":"2018-11-12 18:32:13","cust_id":"27","product":"Win10-key","description":"OEM Windows 10 Home, 64-Bit, 1-Pack, DVD","cost":"98.99","quantity":"1","price":"98.99","timestamp":"2018-11-12 18:32:13"},{"autonum":"89","date":"2019-02-25","customer":"jad Rasul","address":"Washington, DC 20017\r\nSuite 114","invoice":"20190225","sales":"375.00","paid":"0.00","owed":"375.00","tax":"0.00","misc":"2019-02-26 02:22:47","cust_id":"56","product":"Hourly Rate","description":"Commercial Rate - troubleshoot and repair network after Comc","cost":"150.00","quantity":"3","price":"375.00","timestamp":"2019-02-26 02:22:47"},{"autonum":"33","date":"2018-09-02","customer":"Potomac\r\n","address":"Damascus, MD 20872\t\t\t","invoice":"20180902","sales":"467.00","paid":"0.00","owed":"467.00","tax":"0.00","misc":"2018-09-02 22:44:09","cust_id":"23","product":"Hourly Rate","description":"Commercial Camera Installation / Mount / Seal","cost":"150.00","quantity":"2","price":"300.00","timestamp":"2018-09-02 22:44:09"},{"autonum":"30","date":"2017-08-14","customer":"Ann Frank\r\n","address":"Ellicott City, MD 21043\r\n\r\n\t\t\t","invoice":"20170814","sales":"350.00","paid":"0.00","owed":"350.00","tax":"0.00","misc":"2017-08-14 17:56:52","cust_id":"21","product":"Hourly Rate","description":"Residential Rate: Labor/Installs: 6 Kidde i12010S 10 year sm","cost":"350.00","quantity":"1","price":"350.00","timestamp":"2017-08-14 17:56:52"},{"autonum":"21","date":"2017-03-22","customer":"Bikes Music\r\n","address":"Mery Station","invoice":"20160929","sales":"2416.00","paid":"1000.00","owed":"1416.00","tax":"0.00","misc":"2017-03-22 19:51:00","cust_id":"15","product":"Home Depot","description":"Home Depot Supplies for Shelf/mounts/braces/paint.","cost":"128.50","quantity":"1","price":"128.50","timestamp":"2017-03-22 19:51:00"},{"autonum":"83","date":"2019-02-07","customer":"Bikes Music","address":"Mery Station","invoice":"20190207","sales":"95.00","paid":"0.00","owed":"95.00","tax":"0.00","misc":"2019-02-15 20:57:54","cust_id":"50","product":"Hourly Rate","description":"Residential Rate: Consulting/Labor/Installs","cost":"95.00","quantity":"1","price":"95.00","timestamp":"2019-02-15 20:57:54"}]

json.sort(( a, b ) => 
  a.customer.localeCompare(b.customer) || +a.invoice - +b.invoice
 );
console.log(json);
```

Comment: invoice are not asc - the jump from 2019 2017 2017 2018

Comment: First it sorts by `customer`. If 2 items have same `customer` THEN within the customer, it sorts by `invoice`. Check the values for `jad Rasul`

Comment: look at `jad` order of invoice is 20181022, 20190225, 20170412, 20170731, 20180611

Comment: Because they are not the same `customer`. One of them belongs to `jad Rasul` and the other is `jad Rasul\r\n`. First `jad Rasul` values are grouped and sorted based on invoice. Then `jad Rasul\r\n` values are sorted based on `invoice`. If you want them to be considered as same values, then fix your json by removing the `\r\n` values.