# Sorting an array with secondary criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm having trouble understanding the usage of the `Array.sort` function. I have an array that looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    "votes": 3,
    "suggestedDate": "2019-12-01T01:13:00.978Z"
  },
  {
    "votes": 1,
    "suggestedDate": "2020-05-14T21:55:05.879Z"
  },
  {
    "votes": 1,
    "suggestedDate": "2019-12-01T03:22:40.848Z"
  }
]
```

I'm currently using `things.sort((a, b) => b.votes - a.votes)` but this results in a random order when the votes are equal. What sort function should I use to get a stable, date based order when votes are equal?

Answer (score 1):

> What sort function should I use to get a stable, date based order when
>   votes are equal?

Well, you can extend existing `array.sort` callback and check if `votes` are equal. If so, I think `suggestedDate` would be another parameter to overall rank

```js
const things = [{
    "votes": 3,
    "suggestedDate": "2019-12-01T01:13:00.978Z"
  },
  {
    "votes": 1,
    "suggestedDate": "2020-05-14T21:55:05.879Z"
  },
  {
    "votes": 1,
    "suggestedDate": "2019-12-01T03:22:40.848Z"
  }
]

things.sort((a, b) => {

  if (b.votes === a.votes) {
    return new Date(b.suggestedDate) - new Date(a.suggestedDate)
  }

  return b.votes - a.votes

})

console.log(things);
```

[Also consider checking this question as @John mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576714/sort-by-two-values-prioritizing-on-one-of-them)