# Javascript Sort array of objects by value returned by calling method

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of object containing values and methods. One of these methods return a number of which I want to sort by. I also have a few boolean values which determine another sorting order, regardless of the returned number.

```
function reorder(){
    var pinnedTasks = []
    var regularTasks = []
    var finishedTasks = []

    for(var i of tasks){

        if(i.pinned){
            pinnedTasks.push(i)
        } else if(i.done){
            finishedTasks.push(i)
        } else{
            regularTasks.push(i)
        }

    }

}
```

This organizes them into categories, but does not reorder them. I want to have an array with `pinnedTasks` first, `regularTasks` next, and `finishedTasks` last, all reorderd by `i.getDueDaysDiff()` within their own section.

Specifically, I want it sorted by increasing values of `i.getDueDaysDiff()` (least first) for positive values, but decreasing for negative (greatest first). For example, [10, -5, -90, 2] sorted should be [2, 10, -5, -90].

For example, if I have

```
tasks = [
task: regular, getDueDaysDiff() = 1
task: regular, getDueDaysDiff() = -2
task: regular, getDueDaysDiff() = 12
task: regular, getDueDaysDiff() = -50
task: pinned, getDueDaysDiff() = -10
task: pinned, getDueDaysDiff() = 2
task: finished, getDueDaysDiff() = 5
]
```

Reordered should be

```
tasks = [
task: pinned, getDueDaysDiff() = 2
task: pinned, getDueDaysDiff() = -10
task: regular, getDueDaysDiff() = 1
task: regular, getDueDaysDiff() = 12
task: regular, getDueDaysDiff() = -2
task: regular, getDueDaysDiff() = -50
task: finished, getDueDaysDiff() = 5
]
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: Have You tried simply calling array's `sort()` method like this? `tasks.sort((task1, task2) => ... custom compare function...)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort by two values prioritizing on one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576714/sort-by-two-values-prioritizing-on-one-of-them)

Comment: Your desired outcome doesn't make sense: the regular tasks with due days of diff `12` is sorted after regular tasks with due days of diff `1`?

Comment: @Terry This is for a to do list sort of thing, so I would want upcoming things first. ` I want it sorted by increasing values of i.getDueDaysDiff() (least first) for positive values, but decreasing for negative (greatest first).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out:

```
function reorder(){
    var pinnedTasksPos = []
    var pinnedTasksNeg = []
    var regularTasksPos = []
    var regularTasksNeg = []
    var finishedTasksPos = []
    var finishedTasksNeg = []
    
    for (e=0; e<tasks.length; e++){
        let i = tasks[e]
        console.log(i)
        if(i.pinned){
            if(i.dueDaysDiff >= 0) {
                pinnedTasksPos.push(i)
            } else{
                pinnedTasksNeg.push(i)
            }
        } else if(i.done){
            if(i.dueDaysDiff >= 0) {
                finishedTasksPos.push(i)
            } else{
                finishedTasksNeg.push(i)
            }
        } else{
            if(i.dueDaysDiff >= 0) {
                regularTasksPos.push(i)
            } else{
                regularTasksNeg.push(i)
            }
        }
    }

    pinnedTasksPos.sort(compare)
    pinnedTasksNeg.sort(compare).reverse()
    regularTasksPos.sort(compare)
    regularTasksNeg.sort(compare).reverse()
    finishedTasksPos.sort(compare)
    finishedTasksNeg.sort(compare).reverse()

    var newarr = [...pinnedTasksPos, ...pinnedTasksNeg, ...regularTasksPos, ...regularTasksNeg, ...finishedTasksPos, ...finishedTasksNeg]
    return(newarr.reverse())
}

function compare(a, b){
    if(a.dueDaysDiff < b.dueDaysDiff){
        return -1
    }
    if(a.dueDaysDiff > b.dueDaysDiff){
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}
```